# MvvmCross navigate back from TabLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross 5.6.6.
I am using IMvxNavigationService for navigation.
Navigation to view model of tabs from TabLayoutViewModel:

```
tasks.Add(NavigationService.Navigate<TabOneViewModel>());                               
tasks.Add(NavigationService.Navigate<TabTwoViewModel>());                               tasks.Add(NavigationService.Navigate<TabThreeViewModel>());
tasks.Add(NavigationService.Navigate<TabFourViewModel>());
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

All fragments use:

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(FragmentHostViewType = typeof(DamagePanelView), FragmentContentId = Resource.Id.content_frame, AddToBackStack = true)]
```

How can I close (remove) all tab viewmodels (TabOneViewModel, TabTwoViewModel, TabThreeViewModel, TabFourViewModel) when I close the main view model (TabLayoutViewModel)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
    public virtual Task<bool> Close(IMvxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var args = new NavigateEventArgs(viewModel);
        OnBeforeClose(this, args);
        var close = ViewDispatcher.ChangePresentation(new MvxClosePresentationHint(viewModel));
        OnAfterClose(this, args);

        return Task.FromResult(close);
    }
```

Just do a `for` with this function for every page you want to close in the part of your code that you want to close the main view model